# How to save from a dropdown into csv?

Tags: python, csv, tkinter

I would like to save the string value from my Dropdown (tkinter) into a csv data how can i do that? My values are visible in tkinter. But how do I save them in a CSV file.
At the end my csv file should look like this:

```
Name, None, None, Test3
...
```

IF I run these I'm getting this as a Errormessage:

```
actions += ['Test1', 'None', 'None']
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str
```

Comment: your trying to append a list to a string... your error message already says it all

Comment: You need to join an array into string before writing into a file.

Comment: Change `actions = entry.get()` to `actions = [entry.get()]`.  Also Python has a [`CSV File Reading and Writing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module.

Comment: Thx ive got it and its working know.